# In dataloader.io, how can I save my field mapping settings with different files (same column headers)?

Tags: data-loader, import

I'm using dataloader.io to import a large number of records (60K+) into a custom object with a large set of fields.  I'm testing using a small file first (10 rows), but I plan to do a large import next with the remaining data.  There are two different files, but the column headers are exactly the same.  When I go back to my saved import task in dataloader now and change the csv file to be imported, my field mappings get trashed.

Is there a way to save my field mapping settings from the first test import so that I don't have to reset the field mappings when I do the remaining import?

Answer (score 1):

You can do by saving the mapping file and use it for further imports just by selecting the appropriate one rather than creating a new one.

Comment: Thanks!  I figured out that clicking on the up arrow icon (change input) to the right of the pencil icon is the way to go.  When I just uploaded a new file using the pencil icon, it seemed that the mappings got tossed.  With the up arrow icon, the mappings stay constant even if a new file is uploaded.  It just seems like you have to keep column headers exactly the same.  When I tried to delete columns that aren't being used for mapping (I was trying to resolve an error I keep getting: No such property: id for class: org.mule.transport.NullPayload), the import got thrown off.